# How to let a function force bootstrap modal to popup?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar

Hello there : actually i am trying to do some `JQUERY` things in `React` and it is look to me like a magic, i read a lot and search for a way to run the `Bootstrap`, `Modal` with an external `function` .

This is my online code : https://codesandbox.io/s/rwnloz44kq

you will see a `Calendar` and `button` in the end of the page .
When you press the `Button`, the `Modal` working normally and this is what i want to do

( but when I click on the event in the calendar, not when I click the button )

so then i will be able to popup the current event information in the `Modal`.

i used `testClick()` function with  `$("#myModal").modal("show");` as it showen in Bootstrap Doc, but it doesn't work.

Is there any direct way to run the bootstrap modal with an external function ?

Thank you

Comment: You just need to add Bootstrap and Popper as a dependency.

Comment: @Icemanind actually this is the first time i hear about Popper, but i read about prooper.js for the last 30 min's it is look to me not so clear, i tried to apply that on the **codesandbox**  i am not sure if i use it correctly, but did not work, any other suggestions ? and thank you for sure for your reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank for all who try to help i found a nice easy way to solve this trick, it is just kind of twisting but it solve my problem.

i gave the `Modal button` an `id="datepicker"` and i clicked this `button` in my function like so .

```
testClick() {
 $("#datepicker").click()
}
```

and wow the Modal run normally.

The https://codesandbox.io/s/3nkq5zwy6 has been uapdated too .

Have a nice coding ^_^